# Get NullPointerException from method call, but arguments are not null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My apologies in advance for the length of this post, but the inclusion of the two LogCat outputs were necessary to clearly explain my problem.

I am getting a NullPointerException when I call one of the Interface methods of a listener for my custom ViewGroup. The exception occurs at line 264 in the code below.

```
260    ValueTab valueTab = mTabHost.getCurrentlySelectedValueTab();
261    if (this != null && valueTab != null) {
262        Log.i("TabbedSlider", this.toString());
263        Log.i("ValueTab", valueTab.toString());
264        mOnTabbedSliderChangeListener.onSliderValueChanged(this, valueTab);
265    }
```

I have put the method call inside an if statement to ensure that neither of the arguments are null. I have also included a couple of Log statements to help clarify the state of the arguments when the call is made.

- `this` ... is an instance of my custom ViewGroup called `TabbedSlider`
- `valueTab` ... is an instance of a custom child view of TabbedSlider of a type called `ValueTab` which displays a title and float value.

The sequence below explains when this method call occurs:

- An instance of TabbedSlider is instantiated.
- Its various properties are set up.
- It is added to the MainActivity.
- An instance of ValueTab is instantiated.
- Its various properties are set up including assigning it its value.
- It is added to the instance of TabbedSlider.
- The offending method call is made.

I have set a break point on the problem method call and run debug. When I then inspect `this` and `valueTab`, they are setup as I expect.

Since this method call is made immediately after adding the ValueTab to the TabbedSlider, they have not yet been measured, laid out and drawn to the screen (hence the 0 values for their bounds when I log their `toString()`), but these objects are definitely not null.

This is the LogCat output:

```
10-07 10:28:17.952: D/dalvikvm(13357): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 341K, 6% free 7644K/8048K, paused 36ms, total 37ms
10-07 10:28:17.972: I/TabbedSlider(13357): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider{42075068 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f040002 app:id/testSliderA}
10-07 10:28:17.972: I/ValueTab(13357): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.ValueTab{420d8908 VFED..C. ..S...I. 0,0-0,0}
10-07 10:28:17.972: D/AndroidRuntime(13357): Shutting down VM
10-07 10:28:17.972: W/dalvikvm(13357): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41911700)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.soundconception.tabbedslider/com.soundconception.tabbedslider.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider.configureSliderForValueTab(TabbedSlider.java:264)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider.access$1(TabbedSlider.java:256)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider$2.onValueTabSelectionChange(TabbedSlider.java:164)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabHost.selectValueTab(TabHost.java:88)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabHost.valueTabSetup(TabHost.java:72)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabHost.addValueTab(TabHost.java:51)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider.addValueTab(TabbedSlider.java:249)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at com.soundconception.tabbedslider.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-07 10:28:17.972: E/AndroidRuntime(13357):    ... 11 more
```

I can work around this issue by putting the method call in a try/catch block as shown below:

```
    ValueTab valueTab = mTabHost.getCurrentlySelectedValueTab();
    if (this != null && valueTab != null) {
        Log.i("TabbedSlider", this.toString());
        Log.i("ValueTab", valueTab.toString());
        try {
            mOnTabbedSliderChangeListener.onSliderValueChanged(this, valueTab);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.i("TabbedSlider", "Caught NullPointerException");
        }           
    }
```

When I run this, a NullPointerException is caught the first time the method is called for each of my 3 TabbedSlider instances, but any subsequent calls after the first call work fine without raising an exception, as can be seen in the following new LogCat output.

```
10-07 11:36:53.822: D/dalvikvm(14479): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 347K, 6% free 7643K/8052K, paused 36ms, total 38ms
10-07 11:36:53.852: I/TabbedSlider(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider{42076c68 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f040002 app:id/testSliderA}
10-07 11:36:53.852: I/ValueTab(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.ValueTab{420da508 VFED..C. ..S...I. 0,0-0,0}
10-07 11:36:53.852: I/TabbedSlider(14479): Caught NullPointerException
10-07 11:36:53.862: I/TabbedSlider(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider{420b7768 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f040003 app:id/testSliderB}
10-07 11:36:53.862: I/ValueTab(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.ValueTab{4206e0c0 VFED..C. ..S...I. 0,0-0,0}
10-07 11:36:53.862: I/TabbedSlider(14479): Caught NullPointerException
10-07 11:36:53.882: I/TabbedSlider(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider{420c8378 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f040004 app:id/testSliderC}
10-07 11:36:53.882: I/ValueTab(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.ValueTab{42077768 VFED..C. ..S...I. 0,0-0,0}
10-07 11:36:53.882: I/TabbedSlider(14479): Caught NullPointerException
10-07 11:36:53.902: D/HardwareRenderer(14479): Profiling hardware renderer
10-07 11:36:53.952: D/libEGL(14479): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
10-07 11:36:53.972: D/libEGL(14479): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
10-07 11:36:53.982: D/libEGL(14479): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
10-07 11:36:54.022: D/OpenGLRenderer(14479): Enabling debug mode 0
10-07 11:37:15.252: I/TabbedSlider(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider{420b7768 V.E..... ......ID 21,127-779,233 #7f040003 app:id/testSliderB}
10-07 11:37:15.262: I/ValueTab(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.ValueTab{420581e8 VFED..C. ..SP..ID 93,0-186,54}
10-07 11:37:29.292: I/TabbedSlider(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider{420c8378 V.E..... ......ID 21,233-779,339 #7f040004 app:id/testSliderC}
10-07 11:37:29.292: I/ValueTab(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.ValueTab{42074f48 VFED..C. ..SP..ID 186,0-279,54}
10-07 11:37:32.572: I/TabbedSlider(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.TabbedSlider{42076c68 V.E..... ......ID 21,21-779,127 #7f040002 app:id/testSliderA}
10-07 11:37:32.572: I/ValueTab(14479): com.soundconception.tabbedslider.ValueTab{4209bcc8 VFED..C. ..SP..ID 188,0-282,54}
```

It would appear that what this boils down to is something to do with the views not being drawn yet at the time of the first call, but I do not understand why. The view objects at this instant are not null, so why is a NullPointerException raised? Clearly there is a hole in my understanding.

While I can work around the problem with the try/catch block, not understanding why the exception occurs in the first place is going to drive me crazy. Any explanations would be greatly appreciated, and also help this code monkey keep his sanity.

Comment: No need to test condition `this != null`

Comment: Your `mOnTabbedSliderChangeListener` is `null` that's why you're getting `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I added that when trying to debug the problem (out of exasperation), to make it impossible for the method to be called if either argument was null, and yet I still get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Ahh! I was looking in the wrong place. I was adding my listener for the TabbedSlider after adding the ValueTab, but the process of adding a ValueTab calls the listener. Thanks Glenn.